# Зависимость частоты процессора и количества ядер для приложения на nodejs

Tags: node.js, сервер, производительность

Хочу понять на что обратить внимание при выборе дедика для интернет-магазина написаном на nodejs.

Требования:

- линейка Intel Xeon ;
- нагрузка 300 rps (html) + 1500 rps (api);
- время генерации страницы не более 5-10ms на формирование страницы компонентами react.js (формируется 3000-4000 тегов, компоненты в основном функциональные, сильно дроблённые т.е. 3-5 тегов на компонент, на выходе javascript не typescript) + N ms на доступ к базе данных и другим ресурсам;
- pm2;
- PostgreSQL;
- Redis.

Предполагается, что отсутствует кеширование html, только некоторых данных из базы данных в редиску.

Для данных требований лучше 16 * 2.4ГГц или 8 * 3.6ГГц?

PS. На моей домашней машинке html формируется за 15-20ms и 80 rps на 4 ядра (разумеется тест синтетический).

Comment: Вы же знаете, что если Вы не используете `child_process` или `cluster`, то на производительность nodejs количество ядер не влияет? Нода - она же однопоточная.

Comment: Опция -i запускает несколько экземпляров приложения на каждое ядро, поэтому количество ядер влияет. Но как мне сказали js чувствителен к частоте (выполнению байткода), поэтому не совсем ясно где больше выгоды и как сказывается это на подсистеме ввода-вывода. Моё понимание этого очень мизерное, я только начала учиться.